# Libgdx Application cannot be resolved. The hierarchy of type SuperJumper is inconsistent

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, appwarp

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/java-multiplayer-libgdx-tutorial/#what-are-we-going-to-do

However when I clone the project into my computer and I replace the keys(Even before) this problem pops up in the SuperJumperAndroid.java:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type com.badlogic.gdx.Application cannot be resolved. It is indirectly  
referenced from required .class files

- The hierarchy of the type SuperJumperAndroid is inconsistent
```

and

```
The type com.badlogic.gdx.Application cannot be resolved. 
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Quick fix says I should update the build path however I don't really know what to update.

Any help would be appreciated :D 
Thanks in advance

Comment: So, your question is how to fix the build path in an eclipse java project?

Comment: The thing is that I do not know if that is actually the problem. I've changed the build path, but that doesn't seem to fix it...

Comment: Are you exporting gdx.jar from core project?